# Trigger an Elementor popup if user is logged in an billing_phone is left blank

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, elementor

In wordpress I would like to trigger an Elementor popup to always show on a certain page (via shortcode) when the user has not filled in their billing_phone field. Once the field is filled in, the popup would no longer show. Below is what I've tried but it is not working. Any help would be appreciated.

```
function display_elementor_popup_based_on_billing_phone() {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $billing_phone = get_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'billing_phone', true);

    if (!empty($billing_phone)) {
        ?>
        <script>
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
                if (document.querySelector('.elementor-popup-modal#36698')) {
                    document.querySelector('.elementor-popup-modal#36698').click();
                }
            });
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}
add_shortcode('billing_phone_elementor_popup', 'display_elementor_popup_based_on_billing_phone');
```

Comment: what happens when you run this code

Comment: Nothing whatsoever

Comment: Can you give the HTML output for the related element? Are you sure that the targeted element has `elementor-popup-modal` as attribute `class` value and has `36698` as attribute `id` value?

Answer (score 1):

Could be actually caching issue, could be improper usage of the shortcode, could be due to the fact that you aren't "echoing" the Javascript code...

A description of what the code at the moment does would be much appreciated (not just "it isn't working").

Comment: Hello, thank you for responding. I am inserting the shortcode on the target page with Elementors short code widget, pretty basic. Cache is cleared after inserting the code provided via snippet. Not working just means I am not seeing the popup, regardless of empty or non-empty state of the billing phone

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is the popup triggered when you manually do the ".click()" in DevTools console?